# How to solve Error : Could not copy ... Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. - VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am having VS 2017 community edition and I have a console application.
Every time I build I am getting this error.

```
 Error      Could not copy "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.  ConsoleApp1 

 Error      Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe" to "bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\ConsoleApp1.exe' because it is being used by another process. ConsoleApp1
```

This is getting on my nerves as I have to close the VS2017 everytime this error
appears. It runs only one time then I get this error.

Comment: Are you running the VS IDE As Administrator?

Comment: Yes I am running the VS ide as administrator.

Comment: Do you have any anti-virus software running on your machine? If so, either disable it or disable the on-access scan feature.

Comment: Are you sure that no instance of ConsoleApp1.exe is running? A running application usually blocks executable file from overwriting on Windows

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation as you
You can view process by using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Follow these step and you will get the result
In my case the application still run in backgroud i have to close it before building again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found that my antivirus software (f-secure deepguard) causes this problem often when building console-apps, with all versions of visual studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. The anti-virus software puts the executable in quarantine just after it has been built so Visual Studio can not move it to the bin folder. You can easily check if this happens by opening the list with blocked files in the virusscanner.
I have excluded the obj and bin folders of my projects from deepguard protection and that resolves the problem. Shutting down the antivirus alltogether is not a great idea.